# Context Processors are not working with Jinja2 in Django

Tags: django, jinja2

Context Processors are not working with Jinja2(Ver 2.10) in Django(Ver 2.0.5). This is what i have done. Created a context processor as follows:

```
def test_con_proc(request):
return {
    'test_con_proc': "Testing Context Processors",
}
```

And, called it in my template using this:

```
{{ test_con_proc }}
```

Also, added this to settings.py file like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'DIRS': [....)
             ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'environment': '....jinja2.environment',
    },
},
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [.....],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'dashboard.context_processors.test_con_proc',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

So, What't the proper solution for resolving using context processors with Jinja2 in Django?

Comment: Firstly, show the full template settings. Secondly, no of course context processors don't work in jinja2 templates, they are a Django template thing. Why do you need to use jinja2?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I had this scope issue, with Django Template. That's why I used Jinja2 and while searching forums, I found that Jinja2's performance is better than Django Templates. And please don't downvote me. I am a newbie and I don't know many thing in django. Internet is only my resource.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Do you have any suggestions..? I couldn't go back to Django Template, I have to use Jinja2 and should make this work. What's your opinion for using Jinja2 over Django Template.Please reply me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [django-jinja](https://github.com/niwinz/django-jinja) then:

change: `'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',`
to `"BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",`

After that move your context processor to jinja `OPTIONS['context_processors']`

So your settings should look similar to this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [.....],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'dashboard.context_processors.test_con_proc',
            ]
        }
    },
]
```